# vc++ application backwards compatibility

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a software that is developed using VS 2019 with the latest SDK. Running on a Windows 10 OS is OK, but when trying to run on older Windows OS (7 or XP) it doesn't work (The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002)). I already tried installing the necessary vc++ redistributables from 2008 to 2019 but still it won't work. I tried to test using virtual machines with older Windows OS.

Are there any suggestions on how to make this possible? Or do I need to install and compile my program in older versions of Visual Studio to make it compatible with older OS?

Comment: Generally this should work. However you might link some Win10 libraries (or their versions, then you might have to dynamically load the dlls...)

Comment: For Windows XP you need to use a special platform toolset in the project properties IIRC v141 is the newest which still supports XP). v142 which is the latest for VS2019 also works on Win7.

Comment: I have the platform toolset to be v142. and the vc++ redist is for 2015-2019. I also installed it on the Windows 7 vm. It still won't work. As for XP, I tried using the VS2015-Windows XP but the error `C1083` occured

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* is not a problem statement.

Comment: @IInspectable can you give any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Comment: The easy fix: Don't support OS's that aren't supported anymore. Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7 all have reached their end-of-life. Other than that, the error code `0xc150002` translates to `STATUS_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX`. Your application is failing to create the activation context. A debugger will be helpful here.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you very much for your comment. This is much appreciated. As much as I would like to strictly limit the supported OS, we still have clients that support the older versions due to company policies. But still thank you. Now I can run my application on Windows 7, but I'm still working on a solution for XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for ways to figure out what's happening.

Open the app in [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) and see if you can find a problem there. If that fails then [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) would be my next step, but it's not easy to spot a problem in there. Must look very carefully.

Yet another step would be to try to debug the app in that other OS. You can install the Visual Studio there, or you can [debug the app remotely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thank you very much @Dialectus for this information. Using dependencies I figured out what the problem is on Windows 7. As for XP, I'm still working on other possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by the comments above, and also in the answers to other questions about the same error, the problem is dependencies. Usually the solution is trivial (install the obviously missing SDK/runtime).

But sometimes it's not obvious *what* is missing, especially when working with legacy 3rd party components that have dependencies to other Nth party legacy pieces.

The error description (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55), says

```
0xC0150002 STATUS_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX

Windows was unble to process the application binding information. Refer to the system event log for further information.
```

Which doesn't solve the issue, but gives a worthy clue: The system event log.

Open Windows `Event Viewer` app and navigate to `Windows Logs > Application` -- there you should find an error entry (the most recent, quite likely) giving you the details about the missing dependency, or dependencies.

For example, an application that was trying to load `ControlCAN.DLL` (A CAN-bus interface DLL) failed to start because that DLL has a dependency to VS2008 runtime that didn't exist in the system:

```
Activation context generation failed for "C:\path\to\program\ControlCAN.dll". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
```